# Why is my Google Map not loading in my React application?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I’m following this YouTube tutorial to create a Google Map in React with custom HTML markers: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kxYqoY2WwE&t=328s.

However, when trying to load in the map, I get the following error in the console:
[Google Maps Loading Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPjFI.png)

What could be causing this error? I’ve read reports that Ad Block on a browser can cause this but I disabled Ad Block and the error persists.

My Code (I've removed API keys here for security reasons):

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
// /* eslint-disable default-case */
// /* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import { Wrapper, Status } from '@googlemaps/react-wrapper';
import { CircularProgress, Alert } from '@mui/material';
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom';

// require('dotenv').config();

const render = (status) => {
  switch (status) {
    case Status.LOADING:
      return <CircularProgress />;
    case Status.FAILURE:
      return <Alert severity="error">Map Error</Alert>;
    case Status.SUCCESS:
      return <CustomGoogleMap />;
    default:
      return <div>This is the default</div>;
  }
};

export default function CustomGoogleMap() {
  return (
    <Wrapper
      apiKey=""
      version="beta"
      libraries={['marker']}
      render={render}
    >
      <MyCustomMap />
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

const mapOptions = {
  mapId: '',
  center: { lat: 43.66293, lng: -79.39314 },
  zoom: 10,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
};

function MyCustomMap() {
  const [map, setMap] = useState();
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    setMap(new window.google.maps.Map(ref.current, mapOptions));
  }, []);

  return <div ref={ref} id="map" />;
}
```

I tried looking online documentation but found no help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any browser extensions?

Comment: I have a uBlock Origin Extension installed.

Comment: Try disabling that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or provide a working codesandbox link so that we can take a look.

Comment: Does the code I included in my post suffice? That's the complete code causing the problem. I also need the code to work even when browser extensions are enabled, so I can't disable the extension mentioned above.